# Can I use only VR lens for my Nikon D5600?

Tags: lens, nikon, image-stabilization

Nikon D5600 doesn't have image stabilisation. So, I am wondering if I can only use those Nikkor lenses which have VR mentioned? (I am a beginner at DSLR photography and still learning.)

I wanted to buy the AF-S DX NIKKOR 35mm f/1.8G lens but since it doesn't have any VR mentioned, should I not buy it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Will I regret buying an older lens that doesn't autofocus or have image stabilization with my Nikon D5000?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/will-i-regret-buying-an-older-lens-that-doesnt-autofocus-or-have-image-stabiliz?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Nikon cameras with image stabilization in the body. It's always in the lens, if at all. You don't need to buy VR lenses — although of course if you don't, you won't have image stabilization. This is the case with all Nikon DSLRs, not just the D5600.

I understand where you confusion comes from, because higher-end Nikon bodies have autofocus motors, allowing them to drive (mostly, older or special-purpose) lenses which expect that and don't have their own motors. But for VR, the situation is different.

See [Is optical image stabilization a necessary feature for any lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46678/is-optical-image-stabilization-a-necessary-feature-for-any-lens) for some discussion on how vital image stabilization is as a feature overall. The usefulness depend heavily on what you're shooting and how you are doing it. It's also worth noting that while it provides some benefit on a "normal" focal length like 35mm, it's generally more important at longer focal lengths.